# Один объект "проседает" в другой объект при прыжке

Tags: c#, unity3d

Имеется шар, прыгающий по платформам. После того, как упавший шар соприкасается с платформой, этот шар "проседает" внутрь платформы, после чего плавно возвращается в нужную позицию ("всплывает" на поверхность платформы).

К платформе применяется: BoxCollider2D, PlatformEffector2D.

К шару: BoxCollider2D, PlatformEffector2D, RigidBody2D, PlatformPlayer(скрипт).

PlatformPlayer проверяет, приземлился ли шар на платформу. Если нет, то прыжок совершить нельзя.
Вот код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class PlatformerPlayer : MonoBehaviour
{

public float jump = 2300.0f;

private Rigidbody2D body;
private BoxCollider2D box;

void Start()
{
    body = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    box = GetComponent<BoxCollider2D>();
}    

void Update()
{
    Vector2 movement = new Vector2(0, body.velocity.y);
    body.velocity = movement;

    Vector3 max = box.bounds.max;
    Vector3 min = box.bounds.min;

    Vector2 couner1 = new Vector2(max.x, min.y - .1f);
    Vector2 couner2 = new Vector2(max.x, min.y - .2f);

    Collider2D hit = Physics2D.OverlapArea(couner1, couner2);

    bool grounded = false;
    if (hit != null) { grounded = true; }

    if (grounded && Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Space)) { body.AddForce(Vector2.up * jump, ForceMode2D.Impulse); }
       }
}
```

Гравитация выставлена на 500.

Как можно исправить это проседание?

Comment: Не ставить гравитацию 500, например. Это запредельное значение, в нем есть какой-то смысл?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Достаточно было убрать RigidBody2D из шара. По какой-то причине, эта проблема исчезла.

Answer (score 0):

Вместо того, чтобы проверять на столкновение через каждый квант времени, лучше немного поменять логику - **заранее** рассчитать момент столкновения tc, и просчитывать положения в моменты, не превосходящие tc.

После удара рассчитывается новая скорость и следующий момент столкновения.